# Подключение js файлов в yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2, yii

Хочу подключить js файл на определенной странице после всех скриптов, делаю так, но он подключает только после первого jq скрипта

```
$this->registerJsFile('js/gMapSetting.js',
    ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->registerJsFile('js/gMapSetting.js', ['position'=>\yii\web\View::POS_END]);
```